# Python Threading and Subprocesses

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk

so I'm having a problem with threading.  I have included an example similar to the one I am encountering in my program.  When I run the following code, it will only print "hello" after the "Quit" button in the menu has been pressed.  It seems to hang on the subprocess.call().  I don't understand what's going wrong!

Also, I have no experience with threading in Python and I'm new to the language as a whole, so feel free to yell at me for structural flaws, as well as Python programming conventions! :)

Thanks!

```
import threading
import subprocess

import gtk

class TestDaemon:
    def __init__(self):

        # start thread here
        cmdman = CommandManager()
        threading.Thread(target=cmdman.run, args=('CmdThread', 1)).start()

        self.icon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.icon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
        self.icon.set_visible(True)

        self.menu = gtk.Menu()
        self.menu_item = gtk.ImageMenuItem(gtk.STOCK_QUIT)
        self.menu_item.connect('activate', self.quit_app, self.menu)
        self.menu.append(self.menu_item)

        self.icon.connect('popup-menu', self.popup_menu, self.menu)
        self.icon.set_visible(True)

        gtk.main()

    def quit_app(self, widget, data = None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def popup_menu(self, widget, button, time, data = None):
        if button == 3 and data:
            data.show_all()
            data.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu,
                       3, time, self.icon)

class CommandManager:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run(self, *args):
        subprocess.call('echo "hello"', shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestDaemon()
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, if I add a sys.stdout.write() before the subprocess.call(), the sys.stdout.write() will run, but the subprocess.call() will not.

Comment: try setting daemon=True on the thread you are spawning, or joining it before exiting.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!!  Joining it was all I needed! :)

Comment: mind if I put this as an answer? #reputation_whoring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(posted as a comment initially):

join the thread before quitting:

```
class TestDaemon:
    def __init__(self):

        # start thread here
        cmdman = CommandManager()
        self.cmdThread = threading.Thread(target=cmdman.run, args=('CmdThread', 1))
        self.cmdThread.daemon = True
        self.cmdThread.start()

        ...

    def quit_app(self, widget, data = None):
        self.cmdThread.join()
        gtk.main_quit()
```

setting the thread to daemon is for the case that the main thread raises some exception and the join() is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `gtk.mainloop()` instead of `gtk.main()` then it should work.

The problem here is that `gtk.main()` blocks and doesn't let other Threads run, it probably doesn't release the GIL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work... :(  Any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? If I run [your programm with mainloop instead of main](http://pastie.org/4015598) (and moved that call out of the class as it shouldn't belong there) it works as expected.

Comment: For whatever reason, it seems to work every once in a while, but other times, it doesn't...  (Aka if I run it a bunch of times in succession, it will run as expected from time to time.)

Comment: Solved.  Thank you for your help! :)
(Solution was to join the thread.)